# How to convert [AnyObject?] to [AnyObject]

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to do something simple as converting an `[AnyObject?]` to `[AnyObject]`. So the optionals in the array should be unwrapped, and if nil kicked out of the array. Is there an easy way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps:

- filter the array to include all values that are not nil
- map the resulting array by transforming each optional into a non optional

Code:

```
let arrayOfOptionals: [AnyObject?] = [1, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4]

let arrayOfNonOptionals: [AnyObject?] = arrayOfOptionals.filter( { $0 != nil} )

let finalArray: [AnyObject] = arrayOfNonOptionals.map( { $0! } )
```

Of course you can combine filter and map into a single statement:

```
let finalArray = arrayOfOptionals.filter( { $0 != nil} ).map( { $0! } )
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer is

```
let hetro1 : [AnyObject?] = ["a", nil, 2, 3.4, nil];
var hetro2 : [AnyObject] = [];

for val in hetro1{
   if((val) != nil){      
        hetro2.append(val!)
   }
}
println("hetro1 \(hetro1)")
println("hetro2 \(hetro2)")
```